# Image fallback until find a valid one in local assets

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 10+ and having some difficulty how to handle image errors.
I'm building a vehicle catalog, this vehicle catalog has part numbers, a group image and a default image.

When I'm showing the parts of a specific vehicle, I have JSON data with all the information about that part (partnumber, group, default image). I'm showing this part information inside a card that is inside a `ngFor`.

When loading the information of each part inside the `ngFor`, what I'm trying to do is:

1. I want to check if the part number image exists in the assets part number folder.
2. If the part number image exists, I will show it, if not I will check if group image exists in the assets group folder.
3. If the group image exists, I will show it, if not I will show the default image for that part located in the assets default folder.

Is this possible?

I just could do this "fallback" between two images, but not with three.

My HTML code is:

```
<div *ngFor="let part of allParts; let i = index">
<img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/part/partno/{{part.partno}}.png" (error)="handleImgError($event, part.picture)" alt="">
// Others Information about the part...
```

My component code is:

```
async handleImgError(ev: any, picture: string) {
    ev.srcElement.src = `./assets/part/default/${picture}.png`;
    
}
```

Someone already had a situation like this?
It's like a waterfall of fallback until you find the image in the assets folder.

I was looking in the internet, but I didn't find anything about it.

If anyone could guide me, I would be very happy!

Comment: are you trying to check whether an image exists in  source folder or not?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to use angular HTTP service to check whether that image is retrievable or not

like

```
<div *ngFor="let part of allParts; let i = index">
<img class="img-fluid" [src]="validateImage('part.partno' ,'part.picture' )"  alt="">
</div>
```

In your ts file

```
validateImage(image , fallbackImg){
 return this.http
      .get(`./assets/part/partno/${image}.png`)
      .map(res => {
        //image fill be fetched if available
        return `./assets/part/partno/${image}.png`;
      })
      .catch(error => {
       return `./assets/part/default/${fallbackImg}.png`
      });
}
```

you may have to use DOM sanitizer because angular does not allow direct injection of source URL,

Personally, I won't do  this kind of image validation as I have to check each and every time an image loads,